# Setting up a Jupyter Notebooks Server

Tags: python, server, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to access the Jupyter Notebook running on my home Windows PC from my Chromebook.

I've been following the instructions I found [here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html). I've got self-signed certificates, passwords, and filled out the config file etc.

My chromebook connects when I'm at home, but when I'm connected to a different Wi-Fi network it refuses to connect.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set up port forwarding in order to direct traffic to the correct machine on your local network at home.  You'll also need to be able to track what your external IP address is (you can use a dynamic IP service to do this) so that you can even connect to your home network in the first place.

It might be easier to go through a service like pythonanywhere to do this (they have it all set up for you although it sounds like the free tier doesn't include this).  Plus, you can then use their service to deploy a webapp (docker, flask, etc) if that's a direction your project heads.

Comment: pythonanywhere dev here -  we do support jupyter notebooks but not on the free tier...